# iOS-Charts - Can it support two or more markers?

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I have a chart taking shape in iOS-Charts (Daniel Gindi) showing sunrise and sunset against time. I can place a marker against one of the datasets but not both. Is it possible to have a second horizonal marker line?

[image]

The marker lines are instigated with these instructions:

```
    lineChartSunriseDataSet.highlightColor = .orange
    lineChartSunriseDataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled   = true
    lineChartSunriseDataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
    lineChartSunriseDataSet.highlightEnabled = true
    lineChartSunsetDataSet.highlightColor = .red
    lineChartSunsetDataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled  = true
    lineChartSunsetDataSet.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled    = true
    lineChartSunsetDataSet.highlightEnabled = true
```

The markers are differentiated:

```
    let lowerMarker = LowerPillMarker(color: .white, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14), textColor: .orange)
    let upperMarker = UpperPillMarker(color: .white, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14), textColor: .red)
```

I presume I have to set up separate markers? Does iOS-Charts support this?

```
    lineChartView.highlightValue(x: Double(dayOfYear), y: yLower, dataSetIndex: 0, callDelegate: true)
    lineChartView.highlightValue(x: Double(dayOfYear), y: yUpper, dataSetIndex: 1, callDelegate: true)
```

Comment: In the interim I have inserted an UISwitch that allows you to toggle between the two options. It would be preferable if there was a way to draw two horizontal marker lines.

Answer (score 0):

to highlight multiple values use `chartView.highlightValues`

```
chartView.highlightValues([Highlight(x: Double(dayOfYear), y: yLower, dataSetIndex: 0), Highlight(x: Double(dayOfYear), y: yUpper, dataSetIndex: 1)])
```